# Php fails to load data from mysql in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am making a simple php application which has a foreign words dictionary in a mysql database. User uploads a .txt file and gets a html document in which when he clicks on a word gets an instant translation in a javascript alert box.
This is my code . For some reason while parsing a text in a loop mysql db php call does not fetch the data. When printed and ran against the db the queries work fine.
This is my upload code ...

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
$description = $_POST['languages'];

//enabline a file to be displayed as HTML for download start
        $filename = basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]);



        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' .$filename.'.html');
        header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');


//enabline a file to be displayed as HTML for download end

//writting javascript functions to run text to speech on word click start
        echo("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
        echo("<head><META HTTP-EQUIV='content-type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=utf-8'><title>".$filename."</title>");

        echo("<script>");

        echo("function speakIt(b)");

        echo("{");

        echo("if (document.getElementById(\"myCheck\").checked){");

        echo("if ('speechSynthesis' in window){");

        echo("var sometext=b;");

        echo("var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();");

        echo("var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();");

        echo("msg.text = sometext;");


        $textToSpeech =  explode ("-",$description);
        $languageCode = "";

        switch ($textToSpeech[0]) {
            case "de"://German
                $languageCode = "de-DE";
                break;
            case "en"://English
                $languageCode = "en-GB";
                break;
            case "es"://Spanish
                $languageCode = "es-ES";
                break;
            case "fr"://French
                $languageCode = "fr-FR";
                break;
            case "ru"://Russian
                $languageCode = "ru";
                break;
            case "pt"://Portuguese - Portugal
                $languageCode = "pt-PT";
                break;
            case "sr"://Serbian
                $languageCode = "sr-SP";
                break;
            case "ja"://Japanese
                $languageCode = "ja";
                break;
            case "he"://Hebrew
                $languageCode = "he";
                break;
            case "it"://Italian - Italy
                $languageCode = "it-IT";
                break;
            case "el"://Greek
                $languageCode = "el";
                break;
            case "zh"://Chinese - China
                $languageCode = "zh-CN";
                break;
            case "ar"://Arabic - Egypt
                $languageCode = "ar-EG";
                break;
            case "hy"://Armenian
                $languageCode = "hy";
                break;
            case "eu"://Basque
                $languageCode = "eu";
                break;
            case "be"://Belarusian
                $languageCode = "be";
                break;
            case "cs"://Czech
                $languageCode = "cs";
                break;
            case "da"://Danish
                $languageCode = "da";
                break;
            case "et"://Estonian
                $languageCode = "et";
                break;
            case "mk"://FYRO Macedonia
                $languageCode = "mk";
                break;
            case "hu"://Hungarian
                $languageCode = "hu";
                break;
            case "is"://Icelandic
                $languageCode = "is";
                break;
            case "hi"://Hindi
                $languageCode = "hi";
                break;
            case "id"://Indonesian
                $languageCode = "id";
                break;
            case "kk"://Kazakh
                $languageCode = "kk";
                break;
            case "ko"://Korean
                $languageCode = "ko";
                break;
            case "lv"://Latvian
                $languageCode = "lv";
                break;
            case "lt"://Lithuanian
                $languageCode = "lt";
                break;
            case "pl"://Polish
                $languageCode = "pl";
                break;
            case "sk"://Slovak
                $languageCode = "sk";
                break;
            case "sl"://Slovenian
                $languageCode = "sl";
                break;
            case "sv"://Swedish - Sweden
                $languageCode = "sv-SE";
                break;
            case "tr"://Turkish
                $languageCode = "tr";
                break;
            case "uk"://Ukrainian
                $languageCode = "uk";
                break;
            case "vi"://Vietnamese
                $languageCode = "vi";
                break;
            //...add more language support
            default:
                $languageCode = "de-DE";
        }


        echo("msg.lang = '".$languageCode."';");

        //echo("alert(a);");
        echo("speechSynthesis.speak(msg);");

        echo("}");

        echo("}");


        echo("}");


        echo("</script>");


        echo(" <style> ");

        echo("#ebook {");
        echo(" margin: auto;");
        echo("width: 90%;font-size: 200%;@page {counter-increment: page;counter-reset: page 1;@top-right {content: \"Page \" counter(page) \" of \" counter(pages);}}");
        echo("text-align: left;line-height:1.5;font-family: 'Merriweather', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;");
        echo("vertical-align: middle;");
        echo("word-wrap: break-word;");
        echo("border:3px solid #8AC007;");
        echo("padding: 10px;");
        echo("}");

        echo("#header-wrap {");
        echo("position: fixed;");
        echo("text-align: center;");
        echo("background-color: #8AC007;");
        echo("color: white;");
        echo("height: 25px;");
        echo("top: 0;");
        echo("width: 100%;");
        echo("z-index: 100;");
        echo("}");

        echo("</style>");
        echo("</head><body>");

        echo("<div id='header-wrap'>");
        echo("<span>ENABLE / DISABLE TEXT TO SPEECH : <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"myCheck\" id=\"myCheck\" checked=\"checked\"></span></br></br>");
        echo("</div>");
        echo("</br>");
        echo("<div id='ebook'>");
        echo("</br>");
//writting javascript functions to run text to speech on word click end





//chech the details of the uploaded file start


    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "pdf"  ) {
        echo "Sorry, only .txt, .pdf files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } 


//chech the details of the uploaded file end




//setup database connection start
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dictionary";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $table_name=str_replace("-","to",$description);

//setup database connection end

//processing the data start

        $handle = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r");
        if ($handle) {

            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

            $words=explode(" ",$line);

                            foreach ($words as $value)
                              {
                               $translated_word=" ";  

                               $callWorf=str_replace(".", "",$value);
                               $callWorf=str_replace(",", "",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("!", "",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("?", "",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("-", "",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("ß", "ss",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace(":", "", $callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace(";", "", $callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("\"", "", $callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("»", "", $callWorf); 
                               $callWorf=str_replace("«", "", $callWorf); 
                               $callWorf=str_replace("..", "",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=str_replace("\n", "",$callWorf);
                               $callWorf=trim($callWorf);


                               $sql = "select translated FROM ".$table_name." where native='".$value."' limit 1;";
                               //echo $sql;

                               $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                   // output data of each row
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  


                                   $translated_word=$row["translated"];
                                   //THIS IS WHERE I FAIL TO GET RESULTS        ALTHOUGH WHEN I RUN THE STANDALONE QUERY IN WORKS FINE

                                }


                               echo "<span  onclick=\"alert('".$translated_word."');speakIt('".$callWorf."'); \" >".$value." </span>";



                              }   
                              echo '</br>';
        }

            fclose($handle);
        }

//processing the data end

mysqli_close($conn);



echo("</div></body></html>")





?>
```

So at the start I make a html header document where I print using a php echo a javascript function to do text to speech on a word click .
After that I parse the uploaded txt file line by line where for every single word I call the db and seek for the translationb of the word .
For some reason mysql calls fail to provide the results. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong(except for not using prepared statement which I do not need right now)

Comment: You can make your code a lot cleaner by exiting PHP `?>` when dealing with a lot of JavaScript or HTML. And just enter PHP after `<?php`, instead of calling a lot of `echo`s

Comment: have you debugged row count? the parsed table name does exist? checked if mysqli returns any errors?

Comment: I do not get the errors the file is parsed and I get empty string as a result .I will clean the code and remove the php echo from the javascript part ... but that is not the main issue...

Comment: Welp, you're interpolating user-supplied data (`$value`) in your query, so you're basically wide open for a SQL injection attack...

Comment: Of course that's not the main issue @JovoKrneta ;-) Do some basic debugging, such as: `if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { if (mysqli_num_rows($result) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  $translated_word=$row["translated"]; } } else { echo "No rows"; } } else { echo "Query failed: ".mysqli_error($conn); }` -- because you should *never* assume that a query is successful.

Comment: When I do  echo mysqli_num_rows($result); i get all the 0 but when I print the sql string and run it against the db I get the results . The same query in a standalone program without the txt loop provides the good results. The connection string are ok

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` give?

Comment: select translated FROM detoen where native='Der' limit 1;  and when run against the db the translation from German to English is 'The'...

Comment: Does `mysqli_error($conn);` tell you anything?

Comment: This is a part of html source

Comment: <span  onclick="alert(' ');speakIt('auf'); " >auf. </span><span  onclick="alert(' ');speakIt(''); " >
 </span></br><span  onclick="alert(' ');speakIt(''); " >
 </span></br><span  onclick="alert(' ');speakIt('Und'); " >Und </span>